# Login in to a webpage via iOS App

Tags: ios, authentication, webrequest

I couldn't find anything helpful about:

How do I post login-date (username AND password) and login on the webpage?

I know there is AFNetworking, but is there also a solution without it? If not, how do I manage it with AFN ? I can't really get in this AFN-Stuff. (yeah, I know, I suck)

Here's the login Code from the Website:

```
    <div class="moduletable">
                    <form action="/" method="post" id="form-login" >
    <fieldset class="input">
<p id="form-login-username">
    <label for="modlgn_username">Benutzername</label>
    <input id="modlgn_username" type="text" name="username" class="inputbox"  size="18" />
</p>
<p id="form-login-password">
    <label for="modlgn_passwd">Passwort</label><br />
    <input id="modlgn_passwd" type="password" name="password" class="inputbox" size="18"  />
</p>
    <p id="form-login-remember">
    <label for="modlgn_remember">Angemeldet bleiben</label>
    <input id="modlgn_remember" type="checkbox" name="remember" class="inputbox" value="yes"/>
</p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button" value="Anmelden" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="com_users" />
<input type="hidden" name="task" value="user.login" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0yODk=" />
<input type="hidden" name="f8abbfe43b9acc4830bb59c5b35cd9ef" value="1" />   </fieldset>
<!--<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="/component/users/?view=reset">
        Passwort vergessen?</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="/component/users/?view=remind">
        Benutzername vergessen?</a>
    </li>
        </ul>!-->
</form>
    </div>
```

and here is my attempt using a mutableRequest

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.ohg-bensberg.info/component/users/?view=login"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"post"];
NSString *string = @"username=blubbblubb&password=blabla";
[request setHTTPBody:[string dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSError *error=nil;
NSURLResponse *response=nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

For real! THANKS A LOT, I definetly need to get this.

Comment: Other than the parameters you haven't added, what is wrong with your current solution?

Comment: it doesn't show me as logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not send synchronous requests. This is completely unacceptable from a user experience perspective. Use it only for testing.

Second, you are sort of duplicating the request by sending it via `NSURLConnection` *and* the web view. Either you load the result in the return value of your connection call (it is of type `NSData` and you are ignoring it); or you just call the web view `loadRequest` (which is asynchronous).

Third, you should include the `hidden` data fields. In all likelihood your web server needs those to give a valid response.

Comment: can u give my an example how to include the hidden data fields?

Comment: The same as the other fields: `...&option=com_users&task=user.login...` etc. Just add that to your string.

Comment: i change the string to :`NSString *str = @"username=blabla&&password=blub&&option=com_users&&task=user.login&&return=aW5kZXgucGhwP0l0ZW1pZD0yODk=&&f8abbfe43b9acc4830bb59c5b35cd9ef=1";`
 now the webpage gives me an error that my session is outdated and I need to relog, thats an success so far, the page recognizes my POST but I want to log in

Comment: Try using the web view's `loadRequest` only. This is all you have to do from the iOS side. The rest is really a server question (you should then accept this question and ask a new one).

Comment: but the question isn't solved! Im still getting the mentioned error

Comment: It's a different error, if I understand you correctly. Thus, likely a different problem, unrelated to the Objective-C code. There is little we can tell you about your server response with the information available.